# Does the mdbg managed debugger sample exist for .NET 4.0?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, debugging, mdbg

Is there a .NET 4.0 version of the [mdbg managed debugger source](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=38449a42-6b7a-4e28-80ce-c55645ab1310&displaylang=en) ?

I need to port my CPU analyzer, and ICorDebug has changed a bit in .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Recent Update:

The MDBG 4.0 Sample has been released to
[here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=ce94e626-c43d-419c-8538-173f6a042ef5)

Enjoy,
Aaron

Comment: congrats Aaron, glad this project is still alive!

Comment: The link ist dead for me. Redirects to https://www.microsoft.com/library/errorpages/smarterror.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we do plan on releasing an update in the next couple of months. In the meantime, if you're blocked, it's possible for you to update the wrappers yourself, but I realize that's not ideal.

Kind Regards,
Jon

Comment: Thanks Jon, could not have gotten a more official answer :)